# Prevent a page from fully loading in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter, materialize

I have separate views for my navbar (I'm using materialize), home, etc.

This is what my navbar looks like

[image]

It has tabs. When I click a another tab, a method in my controller does this

```
$this->load->view('navbar');
$this->load->view('payables');
```

However, it reloads my whole navbar which prevents my jquery to fulfill it's duty to change the active tab, the page loads but the tab that is selected is still 'HOME'.

How can I prevent my navbar from reloading and load another page at the same time using `$this->load->view()`. I researched that there is something called `ng-route` and `ng-view` in Angular JS that will accomplish this. Is there a counterpart in codeigniter?

Comment: You can do this using PHP means add active or whatever class you are using to highlight the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click in a tab and you "load a method", it means you're launching a whole HTTP request, and you will reload the full page.

To avoid that, you'll need to do it asynchronously. You'll need to create an AJAX request, to load only the part you want. In your view, you'll have to code the JS request that launches a call to the server to render only the part you want to show. When the server answers, your JS will have to allocate that into the page.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. Thanks.